# how to delete a vector that holds other vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have this header code

```
    class BaseFile {
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    BaseFile(string name);
    string getName() const;
    void setName(string newName);
    virtual int getSize() = 0;

};

class File : public BaseFile {
private:
    int size;

public:
    File(string name, int size); // Constructor
    int getSize(); // Return the size of the file

};

class Directory : public BaseFile {
private:
    vector<BaseFile*> children;
    Directory *parent;

public:
    Directory(string name, Directory *parent); // Constructor
    virtual ~Directory(); //destructor
    Directory *getParent() const; // Return a pointer to the parent of this directory
    void setParent(Directory *newParent); // Change the parent of this directory
    void addFile(BaseFile* file); // Add the file to children
    void removeFile(string name); // Remove the file with the specified name from children
    void removeFile(BaseFile* file); // Remove the file from children
    void sortByName(); // Sort children by name alphabetically (not recursively)
    void sortBySize(); // Sort children by size (not recursively)
    vector<BaseFile*> getChildren(); // Return children
    int getSize(); // Return the size of the directory (recursively)
    string getAbsolutePath();  //Return the path from the root to this
};
```

I implemented all the methods and a destructor

```
Directory::~Directory() {
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
    BaseFile *ptr = children[i];
    delete ptr;
}
children.clear();
delete parent;
parent = nullptr;
}
```

and in my main I want to test creating directories inside a directory
like this:

```
int main(int , char **) {
//Environment env;
//env.start();

Directory *d = new Directory("test", nullptr);
Directory *d1 = new Directory("test2" , d);
File *f = new File("test" , 100);

d1->addFile(f);
d->addFile(d1);
delete d;

return 0;
}
```

when I run

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes Assingment1
```

I get a memory leak that is caused from creating a file inside a vector and the vector is inside another vector so the destructor doesn't properly delete it.

```
==20161== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20161==     in use at exit: 56 bytes in 2 blocks
==20161==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 4 frees, 72,912 bytes allocated
==20161== 
==20161== 48 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==20161==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20161==    by 0x10955D: main (Main.cpp:16)
==20161== 
==20161== 56 (8 direct, 48 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==20161==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20161==    by 0x10D5E9: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<BaseFile*>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:111)
==20161==    by 0x10D3F4: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<BaseFile*> >::allocate(std::allocator<BaseFile*>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
==20161==    by 0x10D0BF: std::_Vector_base<BaseFile*, std::allocator<BaseFile*> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:172)
==20161==    by 0x10C8E5: void std::vector<BaseFile*, std::allocator<BaseFile*> >::_M_realloc_insert<BaseFile* const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<BaseFile**, std::vector<BaseFile*, std::allocator<BaseFile*> > >, BaseFile* const&) (vector.tcc:406)
==20161==    by 0x10C335: std::vector<BaseFile*, std::allocator<BaseFile*> >::push_back(BaseFile* const&) (stl_vector.h:948)
==20161==    by 0x10999E: Directory::addFile(BaseFile*) (Files.cpp:42)
==20161==    by 0x10959F: main (Main.cpp:18)
==20161== 
==20161== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20161==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==20161==    indirectly lost: 48 bytes in 1 blocks
==20161==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20161==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20161==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20161== 
==20161== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20161== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

is there a better way to write the destructor so it would delete all the files in the vector?

Comment: The destructor looks ok for me, there is something that we can't see. Can you put a minimal verifiable example with the leak?

Comment: This code introduces undefined behavior due to `BaseFile` not having a virtual destructor.  In particular, this: `BaseFile *ptr = children[i]; delete ptr;`

Comment: Stop using explicit `new` and `delete`.  Use `make_unique()` or `make_shared()`.

Comment: Is it only me who think `addFile` is pretty strange to add a sub-directory? and why add if the constructor already do the same thing?

Comment: `vector<BaseFile*> getChildren(); // Return children` -- Thus the client can now destroy or do anything with those `BaseFile` pointers, all without `Directory` knowing anything was done with them.  This is not a safe design.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Also, C++ is not Java.  If someone were to do this:  `File f("test" , 100); d1->addFile(&f);`, then the destructor for `d1` will attempt to delete a pointer that was not allocated with `new`.  This seems to be a good time to learn about design patterns -- maybe a factory pattern or similar, where the client isn't in the business of doing trickery as I've described, instead your class should be responsible in creating `File` and `Directory` objects.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, your code does not seem too clear on the deletion semantics of directories. It should be clear whether a directory deletes all of its children or whether child directories delete their parents. This also needs to be addressed in copy and move constructors/operators appropriately. Otherwise, you will get leaks.

In addition, your code seems susceptible to **having the same directory deleted multiple times**. This will likely result in crashes or undefined behavior.

If you want to improve your pointer handling, there is a nice way to do that, available from C++11 on, called **smart pointers**. Instead of a raw pointer like `Directory*`, you can use e.g. `std::shared_ptr<Directory>`, which has overloaded `operator->` and `operator*`, so it behaves just like a pointer in your code.

Smart pointers are very convenient in many aspects. For instance, they automatically keep reference counts and delete their encapsulated raw pointer when the last instance goes out of scope. This also works nicely in the case of exceptions, where leaks are likely to happen. An additional benefit is that you don't have to worry about low-level memory handling and have time to focus on the larger context of your application instead.

If you're hearing about smart pointers for the first time, know that there are many types of pointers, suitable for various access and ownership patterns. For more information, check out [the introduction](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) and the [`<memory>` header docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).